# Does enabling I2C disable the use of GPIO pins 2 and 3 (physical 3 & 5)?

Tags: i2c

I'm confused.  I typically grab whatever GPIO pin is handiest when wiring components -- which is often GPIO 2 & 3.  If I enable I2C but don't use an I2C component, can I still use GPIO 2 & 3?  Are the special considerations I have to consider with default LOW/HIGH values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Pi boots it checks to see if I2C bus 1 is enabled and if so sets GPIO 2 and 3 to mode ALT0.  When in mode ALT0 the two GPIO are internally connected to the I2C hardware.

If you change the mode of one of those GPIO you disconnect it from the I2C hardware.  As the connection is broken I2C messages can not be sent or received.  The I2C hardware may be busy but there is no route to the outside world - messages are just discarded.

You will automatically change the GPIO mode and break the connection to the I2C hardware when you use GPIO 2 or 3 in a script.  E.g. in a Python script you will normally set the GPIO to be in INPUT or OUTPUT mode.

The only special consideration is that GPIO 2 and 3 have hard-wired 1k8 pulls to 3V3 (they are needed when functioning as an I2C bus).  You need to be aware of those comparatively strong pulls with any circuit you design.

By the way you can restore the I2C functionality (without rebooting) by setting the GPIO back to mode ALT0.

E.g. with my pigs utility

`pigs m 2 0 m 3 0 # set GPIO 2/3 to mode ALT0`

Comment: I'm going to have to think about this a bit.   So... if I configure a Pi for I2C (as part of a standard setup process) but don't use any I2C devices, I can happily ```GPIO.setup(PIN,GPIO.OUT)``` and use that pin (2/3; 3/5) in the same way as if I hadn't config'd I2C.  Right?  That seems like a no brainer.

Comment: That is correct (as long as by don't use you also mean don't connect any I2C devices to the bus).

Comment: @joan when you say the bus does that include not connecting any i2c devices to the -alternate- i2c pins on the pi or is that a separate bus?

Comment: @Montagist The I2C bus is only accessible via GPIO 2/3 (ignoring Pi4 and later for now).  The I2C bus may be implemented using different GPIO but they are not accessible to the user.