# Pullup for pins 2 and 3 -- practical consequences?

Tags: gpio

In [this awesome answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117554/147100), the author wrote this about pings 2 and 3 in the PI:

> The only special consideration is that GPIO 2 and 3 have hard-wired 1k8 pulls to 3V3 (they are needed when functioning as an I2C bus). You need to be aware of those comparatively strong pulls with any circuit you design.

What does the strong pull affect, in practical terms?

Comment: "You need to be aware of those comparatively strong pulls with any circuit you design" what circuit are you designing?

Comment: "Any circuit" <-- that's what the awesome answer says, clearly. "Any"

Comment: The pull-ups are actually only relevant when the pin is used as an input.  This is very literally a simple question about [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law).

Comment: the resistor affects the design of any circuit that is connected to the pin ... when designing a driver circuit, or an input circuit, include the resistor in the final design

Comment: So, if I were to add a pull up resistor, it will be effectively in parallel with the one in the Pi?

Comment: "that's what the awesome answer says, clearly. Any" -  so just do what it says when you design any circuit. Joan is just stating the obvious (for those who may be unaware of the pullup). If you are't designing any circuit then ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "strong pull" is a term used to describe a relatively low-resistance pull-up resistor. Conversely, a "weak pull" is a relatively high-resistance pull-up.

There is a good general explanation of "weak vs. strong" in [this answer on EE SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/76381/187550). In *practical terms*, and in the case of the RPi, the "strong pull" resistor values provide the I2C signals a bit more resistance to noise/spurious signals which could corrupt the clock and/or data - leading to comm failures.

RPi does not share their design approaches, so we can't tell you **how** they arrived at these particular values. As a guess, I would say that they were chosen empirically, and with a desire to make the I2C bus as robust as possible given all other system constraints.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much,